# via Listbox1-click populate Listbox 2 Accordingly

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, filereader, arrays

I'm loading values from file via **File.ReadAllText**, straight into ListBox1

the file is .txt - Comma Separated.

HealthyFood.Txt

**content**:

Dairy,Fruits,Vegetables,Whole Grains

to populate Listbox1 (LstBox_HealthyCat) in its simple way (no Condition applied ) With little Help of my Helper-Method actually, so I will not have repeat my code for the other files(:

```
public string GetFileContent(string FileName)
{
    string Filecontent = "";
    string ExtTXT = ".txt";
    string initialDir = @"G:\RobDevI5-3xRaid-0\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\x64\Debug\HealthFood\";

    Filecontent = File.ReadAllText(intialDir + FileName + ExtTXT);
    return Filecontent;

}

string[] HealthyFood = GetFileContent(HealthyFood).Split(',');
LstBox_HealthyCat.Items.AddRange(HealthyFood);
```

So now the result is ListBoxMainCategory will be

**Dairy**

**Fruits**

**Vegetables**

**Whole Grains**

So Far it's good example for new developers

My Question is, next step I would like to populate
The Sub-Category oF HealthyFood e.g Fruits

fruits.txt

**content:**

Apple,Banana,Cherry,Dates

So when I will click on Main Category: **Fruits**
it will populate ListBox2 with selection of ListBox1
and rest of items availble in listBox1 as well(when clicked).

**alternative to my**

```
 Filecontent = File.ReadAllText(intialDir + FileName + ExtTXT);
```

**Tim Schmelter's code:**

```
 System.IO.Path.Combine(initialDir, item + ExtTXT);
```

**path combine** ... nice one !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if i understood your requirement correctly, you want to fill the second ListBox according to the SelectedItem(s) of ListBox1. For instance, if `fruit` was selected then `fruits.txt` should be used and so on. Then this might help you:

```
const string initialDir = @"G:\RobDevI5-3xRaid-0\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\x64\Debug\HealthFood\";
const string ExtTXT = ".txt";

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    foreach (String item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        String path = System.IO.Path.Combine(initialDir, item + ExtTXT);
        if(System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            listBox2.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path).Split(','));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have files with the same name of the category in ListBox1, then, all you have to do is pass this category to your helper function and use the result to populate ListBox2.

This could be easily done in the SelectedIndexChanged event

```
private void LstBox_HealthyCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox. 
   string curCategory = LstBox_HealthyCat.SelectedItem.ToString();
   string[] subCatItems = GetFileContent(curCategory).Split(','); 

   // Clear the previous list of foods from the second listbox
   ListSubCategory.Items.Clear();
   ListSubCategory.Items.AddRange(subCatItems); 
}
```

Keep in mind that this example assumes you have the following text files in the folder identified by the `initialDir` variable inside the GetFileContent method

- Dairy.txt
- Fruits.txt
- Vegetables.txt
- Whole Grains.txt

Comment: thank you for your answer though i would like to learn the right syntax ,like in the situation to reach my left ear with my left hand not doing roundabouts (:

Comment: thank you steve thanks tim Reviewing both Answers see what sits in my mind more comfortably...and wich is more cpu interaptes eficieny if they're both easy to comprehend

Comment: reading steve's Code is easy ! but the part of me that looks for the higher level vocabulary(as in words Language using higher words) so i will think i am sophisticated gonna check further on tim's code(:

Comment: "security" issues regarding my initial helper function , i notesd that i didn't check for existense of data (exeptions etc') as mentiond by steve regarding the existense of spoken files . yes we do know they exist but we want to be worscase-Ready ... we suppose to be ... as (me) future pro developers , bulet proof codes (:

Comment: You could add a security layer around your GetFileContent. First, add an exception block (try/catch), then check if you have the file requested via File.Exists and handle the negative situation (return an empty string). Moreover, the location specified in initialDir, should be read from a configuration file. I suggest you to take this habit and never use hardcoded paths. They have a nasty habit. Never exist on your future customer's machine.

Comment: as with all ini (or cfg)Extentions ... right ... thought about it just today actually... thx steve